# Discord.js Trouble comprehending members.role (Formatting)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, message, roles

Problem: Cannot get this funtion to return, NOT BREAK, if the user does not have the defined role. Tried a few different formats but here it is clean. Every time i try an else if i can an unexpected symbol so i think my formatting is bad.

Goal: Implement a Role Permission.

```
     bot.on('message', function(message) {
    /* If message content not start with prefix stop function. Better do negative check, because it will avoid nesting. */
if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return 
    /* if message startsWiht prefix declarate a command */
let command = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(" ") + 1, message.content.length);
    /* Now we can check user role */
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('691441168000483409')) { 
        /* if Message.member has no target role stop function, send error message, and delete after 5s */ 
        message.reply('You has no permission for this').then(msg => {
            msg.delete({ timeout: 2000 }); 
        });
        return;
    }

bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case "aa1":
            bot.commands.get('aa1').execute(message, args);
        break;

        case "aa2":
            bot.commands.get('aa2').execute(message, args);
        break;




    }

});
});


bot.login(token);
```

Update: The permission part is working alright when the using doesn't have the role, but it does NOTHING when a user has the role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you using discord v12 version ? 
for discord v12 you can use:

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('ROLE ID')) return message.reply('You has no permission for this')

if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => ['ID','ID2'].includes(role.id))) return message.reply('You has no permission for this')
```

for discord v11 you can use:

```js
if (!message.member.roles.has('ROLE ID')) return message.reply('You has no permission for this')

if (!message.member.roles.some(role => ['ID','ID2'].includes(role.id))) return message.reply('You has no permission for this')
```

**V2**

```js
bot.on('message', function(message) {
    /* If message content not start with prefix stop function. Better do negative check, because it will avoid nesting. */
if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return 
    /* if message startsWiht prefix declarate a command */
let command = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(" ") + 1, message.content.length);
    /* Now we can check user role */
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('691441168000483409')) { 
        /* if Message.member has no target role stop function, send error message, and delete after 5s */ 
        message.reply('You has no permission for this').then(msg => {
            msg.delete({ timeout: 2000 }); 
        });
        return;
    }
    /* Now you can enter code whats you need */


});
```

**V3**

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
        /* If message content not start with prefix stop function. Better do negative check, because it will avoid nesting. */
    if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return 
    /* if message startsWiht prefix declarate a command */
    let command = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(" ") + 1, message.content.length);
    /* Now we can check user role */
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('691441168000483409')) { 
        /* if Message.member has no target role stop function, send error message, and delete after 5s */ 
        message.reply('You has no permission for this').then(msg => {
            msg.delete({ timeout: 2000 }); 
        });
        return;
    }
    switch(args[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case "aa1":
            bot.commands.get('aa1').execute(message, args);
        break;
        case "aa2":
            bot.commands.get('aa2').execute(message, args);
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null" Do i need to define user.id or something? let user.id = 'IDOFROLE'? I understand the concept of what it is doing but am unsure what it referring back to when it executes.

Comment: I did some edits, whats version return error? You need put this code into `bot.on(message =>`

Comment: Final edit: Sorry for editing so much and no being decisive on what i exactly wanted. I have made one last edit, close to working. All i need is to implement else if, which i have changed the title to reflect. Thanks for the help so far, i appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @BrianChambers,no problem :), i\`m add v2 version. This must works fine. You can stop code execute with return on some `if` checks.

Comment: Fortunately that is working much better than what i had!!! BUT it is not doing anything when the user has the role. I think the end formatting is wrong?

Comment: just add code here `/* Now you can enter code whats you need */` and then function will do what\`s you want. You can check if add `console.log('all right')`. Make it as Answer if it\`s work for you :)

Comment: I edited the original to be the same as my code now, it's doing all kinds of funny stuff now. Quadruple messages is one of the things.

Comment: Add example on v3 code version, if you need this check on specific command, just put the check block into command file.

Comment: Once again my formatting bites me in the butt, i almost had it like that on my new revision. Time to hit the books. Thank you so much!

Comment: NEW PROBLEM - Unfortunately when a user DM's the bot it breaks completely. Any way to check if it's a DM and reject it completely or?

Comment: @BrianChambers just add `if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return` after `bot.on(message =>`  : )